# PowerQuery formula bar error cycling reference

Tags: powerquery

What is wrong with this pquery formula; Expression.Error: A cyclic reference was encountered during evaluation.

```
Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom", each Table.SelectRows(
 tblOrders (2),
(InnerTable)=>InnerTable[Order Date] = [Category]
)[Value])
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and copy the complete code

Comment: What do you mean

Comment: Use the Advance Editor in Power Query and copy all the code you have, otherwise it's really difficult to know what's causing the cyclic reference.

Comment: @RicardoDiaz  I am trying to use SUMIF in powequery. Formula lacks only List.SelectRows..if it will help you

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing the whole code